# AJAX JSON parse returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using jquery and javascript, with an ajax call to get all the information from a json file. The json file loads fine, and perfectly adds the points to the map, but there is still an error in the console.

```
"TypeError: obj[i].info is null"
```

Even though every point is inserted correctly and has the "info" attribute inside them, why does jquery give it a null value?

Example code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
}).success(function(data){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj);
        $.each(obj, function(i, item){
            taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].info.latitude,obj[i].info.longitude));
        });

}).error(function(data){
    console.log("Error with data: " + data);
});
```

My JSON:

```
[{
        "id" : 1,
        "ip" : "165.242.13.8",
        "referer" : "www.facebook.com",

        "info" : {
            "request" : "165.242.13.8",
            "ip" : "165.242.13.8",
            "country_code2" : "JP",
            "country_code3" : "JPN",
            "country_name" : "Japan",
            "continent_code" : "AS",
            "region_name" : "11",
            "city_name" : "Hiroshima",
            "postal_code" : "",
            "latitude" : 34.3963,
            "longitude" : 132.45940000000002,
            "dma_code" : null,
            "area_code" : null,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Tokyo"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: use 'dataType: 'json',

Comment: I've edited my code, and set datatype as json, parsing is correct but still there is an error

Comment: You don't need $.parseJSON(data) if you specify dataType:json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
}).success(function (data) {
    var obj = data;
    console.log(obj);
    $.each(obj, function (i, item) {
        var pushString = item.info.latitude + ',' + item.info.longitude;
        var googleLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(pushString);
        taxiData.push(googleLatLong);
    });
}).error(function (data) {
    console.log("Error with data: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `$.each` wrong.

`each` already takes *each* entry and gives it to you as the item.

use:

```
$.each(obj, function(i, item){
            taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(item.info.latitude,item.info.longitude));
        }); //Notice I don,t access the obj Object
```

Comment: again it says item[i] is undefined

Comment: Item is the object in your array, not the array itself

Comment: I've set item as taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(item.info.latitude, item.info.longitude)); but still the error continues, **but it prints the points to the screen**

Comment: @Yagiz use`item` not `item[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,
you can set

```
dataType : "json"
```

and don't do

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

your data will already be an object

Secondly,
this code works

```
console.log(obj);
$.each(obj, function(i, item){
    console.log(obj[i].info.latitude);
    console.log(obj[i].info.longitude);
    console.log(item.info.latitude);
    console.log(item.info.longitude);
});
```

item === obj[i]